# Can't Hide Then Show Control In Angular 4 Reactive Form Using Select

Tags: angular

I am unable to toggle between hiding and showing a control using a select embedded in an Angular 4 reactive form. The following shows the issue: https://plnkr.co/edit/s7wYqy3Oa9eGmvOY3sNX?p=preview. If you select the "Name" option, the address field will be hidden as expected. If you select the "Name and Address" option afterwards, it does not show.

Here is the template for the component:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" novalidate="">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Choose</label>
    <select class="form-control" formControlName="isNameOnly">
      <option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option.value">
        {{option.name}}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input class="form-control" formControlName="name" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group" [hidden]="myForm.controls.isNameOnly.value">
    <label>Address</label>
    <input class="form-control" formControlName="address" />
  </div>
  <pre>{{myForm.controls.isNameOnly.value}}</pre>
</form>
```

Here is the definition of the component:

```
import { Component, Input, OnChanges }       from '@angular/core';
import { FormArray, FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-form',
  templateUrl: './form.component.html'
})
export class MyFormComponent implements OnChanges {
  myForm: FormGroup;
  options = [
    {name: 'Name Only', value: true}, 
    {name: 'Name and Address', value: false}
  ];

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder
  ) {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      name: '',
      address: '',
      isNameOnly: false
    });
  }

  ngOnChanges() {}
}
```

Comment: `[hidden]="myForm.controls.isNameOnly.value == 'true'"` https://plnkr.co/edit/7ub2fy7CBdBA46i4qkvv?p=preview your values in select are true and false in string form so just check for the string true

Comment: @Huangism your version is better :)

Comment: @Vega feel free to update your answer with this alternative solution

Comment: I was going to ask you to post your answer and explain it as I am thrilled by 'true'. How it came a string?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Update hidden to the following checking the true string

```
[hidden]="myForm.controls.isNameOnly.value == 'true'"
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/7ub2fy7CBdBA46i4qkvv?p=preview

I believe `myForm.controls.isNameOnly.value` returns a string and `[hidden]` evaluates it as an expression and since "true" or "false" are both non empty strings, so hidden is always true