# Angular: Adding events to FormControls added dynamically in FormArray

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm using `Angular 4` and I'm creating a page where user can create a format consists of Hash, sequence and constant value. User can add them in any order,so for this purpose I'm creating them dynamically using `FormArray`

HTML Code is:

```
 <div formArrayName="components"
    *ngFor="let c of components.controls; let i=index">
   <div [formGroupName]="i">
     <div class="form-group row">
       <div class="col-md-3">
         <select type="" id="component" class="form-control" placeholder="" 
             formControlName="component">
           <option value="Sequence">Sequence</option>
           <option value="Hash">Hash</option>
           <option value="Constant">Constant</option>
         </select>
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-2">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" formControlName="limit" />
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="value" />
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-2" style="color:red" (click)="deleteRow(i)">
           <fa name="times"></fa>
       </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The code above will produce an output like this.
[image]

**Question** How to bind events with these dynamically created controls? For example on selection of certain value in drop down I want to hide the input control next to it.

Comment: Take a look at this question, it seems relevant.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45357397/cant-hide-then-show-control-in-angular-4-reactive-form-using-select

Comment: I'm adding these controls on runtime and need to bind event to it. that link doesn't create the dropdown at runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind the event to a function that takes the index and then retrieve the controls from the formArray in the function using the index

In your HTML

```
 <select type="" id="component" class="form-control" placeholder="" 
             formControlName="component" (change)="onChange(i)>
```

In your ts file

```
let row = components.controls[pos] as FormGroup 
//row now contains all the controls bound to it you can access the controls like the following 
let value = row.controls["component"].value
```

Or if you just want to hide the input without any complex conditions you can try this in your HTML

```
 <input type="number" class="form-control" formControlName="limit" *ngIf="c.get('component').value != 'whatever'"/>
```

Comment: Won't this solution break if for some reason your FormArray supports some sort of reorder functionality?

Comment: @TiagoMartins check out this question for reordering in the FormArray https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46459266/angular-how-to-reorder-items-in-formarray